# Upgrading SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2014 for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Hi SharePoint Experts,

I would like to ask your advise. There is a planned upgrade of SQL Server from 2008 R2 (server will be decommissioned) to a new server with SQL 2014. What's the latest Cumulative Updates that needs to be installed which supports SQL Server 2014? How should I install them? As far as I know the patch has to be installed sequentially but I don't know which patch should I start installing.

Should you need further details, please advise so that I could supply the other information relevant for my inquiry.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, your SharePoint 2013 farm should be at least May 2014 CU in order to work with SQL server 2014. [Check this software requirement here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#section4)

As you are moving to new servers.I would do in the following order

- Make sure Minimum May 2014 CU installed on SharePoint farm
- Build the new Sql Server 2014
- Shut down SharePoint Sevices, IIS
- take the backup of the Database backup from SQL
- Restore them on new SQL Server
- Now create the alias on the SharePoint server
- Start the SharePoint services and IIS.
- Test now.

Check this link for more info: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2014/06/10/moving-sharepoint-databases-to-another-server-without-reconfiguring-sharepoint/

Also this one https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396